# unix awk pattern help, aka. search not working

Tags: search, awk

newbie here asking for help

I need to only list lines that are in certain format:

`<server>: (<#> dbs)<disk> <total>G <used>G <free>G <perc>% <mount>`

`wakanda: (5 dbs)/dev/sda1 12G 24G 12G 50% /`

all lines that do not match this should not be displayed
so far i tried to kinda brute force it by trying:

`awk '$0~p' p=".*:*dbs*G*G*G*" ./testFile`

but this also lists lines like:

server: (207 dbs)

I dont understand why it would straight up ignore the Gs, I've been googling for considerable time now and I'm currently completely lost, please help

Comment: `*` matches _zero or more_ instances, which is why the `G`s are ignored. I find checking my regexes in an online checker helps me avoid problems. eg. https://regexr.com

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/.*dbs.*([0-9]+G ){3}/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** `awk` works on method of condition(regexp) then action. Here I am putting a check to look for regex `.*dbs.*([0-9]+G ){3}` in current line and if regexp is found then no action is mentioned so by default printing of line will happen.

Comment: That was very quick, and seem to be very correct, thank you.
I dont want to be a pain in the ass, but can you please explain it to me like im stupid if you have time?

Comment: @Zecmirit, sure added detailed explanation too now, cheers.

Comment: well ive looked into it a bit better and it omitted two lines from the test files that i dont think it should have:

mysql5: (133 dbs)/dev/sda1 69G 68G 1.5G 98% /
mysql16: (138 dbs)/dev/xvda 40G 34G 6.4G 84% /

any idea why?

Comment: @Zecmirit, it was based on your shown attempt only. Please do update samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: okay so the correct input looks like this:
`<server>: (<#> dbs)<disk> <total>G <used>G <free>G <perc>% <mount>`

`mysql4: (648 dbs)/dev/sda1 58G 30G 25G 56% /`

`mysql5: (133 dbs)/dev/sda1 69G 68G 1.5G 98% /`

`frodo: /dev/xvda1 (1163 dbs) 37G 21G 16G 57% /`

anything no in this format should be discarded, which is kinda working except lines:

`mysql5: (133 dbs)/dev/sda1 69G 68G 1.5G 98% /`

`mysql16: (138 dbs)/dev/xvda 40G 34G 6.4G 84% /`

jesus, sorry for formatting, this is literally my first post :/

Comment: @Zecmirit, please do add samples in your question as comments are not meant to show samples.

Comment: You want to edit your question to include all these samples, and explain in more detail why some of them should be excluded.